# How can I show more than 19 characters in file names when browsing directories in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, directory

I'm trying to browse a directory (for server logs, in this case) and I can't seem to find any way to tell Apache to show more then the first 19 characters of the filenames in the directory, followed by "...>". Unfortunately, they all have the same first 19 characters, so I can only tell them apart by the date stamp column. Is there a way to fix this - a querystring parameter, for example?

It's Apache/2.2.6 (Unix) DAV/2 Server, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IndexOptions NameWidth=*
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually asking more from a browsing point of view, rather than server admin (which is why I'd posted it on SuperUser), because I don't have access to change the server's settings. But your link has what I was looking for: if you add "F=0" to the URL, it shows the entire names. Thanks!